# Most efficient way to redirect any request to HTTPS on Apache?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Is it better this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.ltd/$1 [R,L]
```

I tryed all of them, they work, and I couldn't notice any noticeable difference in site loading time. Despite this, I would like to understand what they do exactly on the 2nd line.

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately, it depends on your setup.

In the first example, you are checking for the protocol based on the [`X-Forwarded-Proto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto) header. As you can see, this is set by the proxy or load balancer sitting in front of your server so, if you don't have one, this header might be blank, even if the client initiated a secure connection and you'd still perform the redirect.

The second one is a variable set directly by the web server based on what connection it received, but it's dependent on [`mod_ssl`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars) so it *might* not be available.

The last one it just checks the port, there's no additional information on the protocol used, it's up to you to figure it out if you are running apache in non-standard ports.